# Call controller function from view! asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Is there any method to call a controller function from View without losing data
For example if I want to call ExportToExcel function from CandidateView.

Using this statement:

```
 function ExportList() {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Candidate")';
    }
```

will create a new Controller and I lose my model data. But I need it for export.

Comment: Use Ajax call..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ExportList() {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Candidate", new { param1 = Model.parama1, .... } )';
    }
```

This is will solve your problem, but if your function make export I would recommend put that in a Form and Submit a form with values i need to controller.